# Clicking an input type of read only doesn't update the value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have used three input boxes of type number in which I will get values from the first two input boxes and multiply it and display the result in the third input box which is read-only.

Whenever the value gets changed in the first two input boxes the result gets updated.

But when i click the third input box (read-only field) and give values in the first two input boxes it doesn't show the result in the third input box.

Can anyone tell me why it occurs?

```html
    <label class="item item-input InputFormFull">
     <span class="input-label">{{"tradeothercharges_message" | translate}} (+)</span>
     <input stopccp decimalpoint
            type="number" maxlength="9" ng-model="vm.other_charges" ng-change="vm.onValueChange()">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input InputFormFull">
     <span class="input-label">{{"tradeamtgiven_message" | translate}}</span>
     <input stopccp decimalpoint
     type="number" maxlength="9" ng-model="vm.trade.amount_out" placeholder="0" ng-change="vm.onValueChange()">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input InputFormFull">
     <span class="input-label">{{"tradedebitcaputre_message" | translate}} (-)</span>
     <input type="number" ng-value="vm.trade.amount_in - vm.trade.amount_out" placeholder="0" ng-readonly="true">
    </label>
```

Comment: How can you write value in read-only `input` field?

Comment: @Mamun using ng-value i have written it

Comment: Yes, you can do that only for the first time when the control is just initialized. But any further update is not possible for read-only field.

Comment: Whether the `ng-change` directive is working as expected? Is the function `vm.onValueChange()` is getting called?

Comment: @Madhavan.V it is working as expected. problem occurs only when the readonly field is touched

Comment: Can you create a demo that exemplifies the failure? What if you set the input to disabled? Do you need an input, or can you just interpolate {{ a - b }}?

Comment: It's weird.. It seems like 'ng-readonly' doesn't work. How about using 'disabled'?

Comment: I've made an fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/dgt6rx5s/5/

Comment: And https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/dgt6rx5s/7/ this is your original codes. I don't know what is your problem. 'ng-readonly' seems like working well.